# Why did Kelly receive the power of telepathy?

Tags: misfits

Kelly's original power is telepathy, and all of the Misfits gang have powers to specialize round their personalities. Nathan’s is immortality, because he is cocky and seems like he is invincible. Alisha's is when people touch her, they instantly want to have sex with her, and in her past, she drew a lot of attention from guys in a sexual way. Simon's is invisibility, because he felt like he was invisible.. and Curtis regretted a lot of things in the past – so that's why he got the power to turn back time.

Kelly's power (telepathy) must revolve around her personality, so why did she get it?

Answer (score 9):

Kelly was "constantly judged for her class" ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misfits_(TV_series))) and so had an inherent tendency to wonder what other people thought about her.  Telepathy is the natural complement to that.

If I recall (haven't watched in a while), she acted as if she didn't care what other people thought about her, but had a layer of insecurity underneath.  Wanting to know what other people *really* think about her is natural for someone like that.

Comment: Ah, thanks ^ that really helped. I actually assumed it was something like that, because she was always like, a bit gobby I'd say. So, she always thought what people thought about her.